# How to automatically update a list of all sheets names in a spreadsheet when a Sheet is added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a spreadsheet where i have a sheet called "sheetsNames". In this sheet i'm trying to make a list of all sheets names which are currently  in the spreadsheet.

I've found the following code which i'm using and it works fine:

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

In the sheet "sheetsNames" in cell A1 I manually set the value to "=sheetnames()" to run the code above.

My problem is that everytime I add a new sheet to the spreadsheet the list isn't adding the new sheet name automatically.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, custom functions cannot automatically update the list of sheets on your spreadsheet since the code doesn't check for any updates on objects or events happening on the sheet for it to be executed.

**Suggestion:**

You can change the code to this format, and create a simple `onEdit` or `onOpen` trigger instead. You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) for simple triggers. Like so:

[image]
In my case, I used onOpen so that the function runs every time the sheet is opened.

```
function sheetnames() {
    var out = new Array()
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var getsheet = sheets.getSheets();
    for (var i=0 ; i < getsheet.length ; i++) out.push([getsheet[i].getName()])
    Logger.log(out);
    sheets.getRange('C1').setValues(out); //set value of the array on your preferred cell.
    
    }
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply! I'm getting an error message: 

"Exception: You do not have permission to call setValue (Zeile 66)."

Comment: Hello @axis9011, check first if there is an authorization page that pops up whenever you tried to run the script for the first time. Make sure that pop ups are enabled on your browser as well just to make sure

Comment: I'm still getting an error message. Do I miss something? Can you explain the part you added to the code?

Comment: `Logger.log(out)` is just a method to check the value of your array. Wherein `sheets.getRange('C1').setValue(out);` gets the specific cell where you would want the list to populate. Would you be able to share a sample of your sheet so that we can check?